# linking two tables together with same username

Tags: php, mysql, forms

i have two tables USERS and CASH_FLOW_PLAN

I would like to carry over the username from the USERS table of the currently logged in user and use that as the primary key to the CASH_FLOW_PLAN table, that way the infomration from CASH_FLOW_PLAN can be printed, carried to a new page... etc etc... So for example i have logged in and i get redirected to a page called cash-flow-plan.php where i then type in a bunch of salary information and numbers that are stored in the CASH_FLOW_PLAN table with the current logged in users username.

i have a session carried over to every page

```
function startSession(){
  global $database;  //The database connection
  session_start();   //Tell PHP to start the session

  /* Determine if user is logged in */
  $this->logged_in = $this->checkLogin();

  /**
   * Set guest value to users not logged in, and update
   * active guests table accordingly.
   */
  if(!$this->logged_in){
     $this->username = $_SESSION['username'] = GUEST_NAME;
     $this->userlevel = GUEST_LEVEL;
     $database->addActiveGuest($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $this->time);
  }
  /* Update users last active timestamp */
  else{
     $database->addActiveUser($this->username, $this->time);
  }

  /* Remove inactive visitors from database */
  $database->removeInactiveUsers();
  $database->removeInactiveGuests();   

  /* Set current url */
  $this->url = $_SESSION['url'] = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
 }
```

Comment: What have you done and where are you stuck? Code snippet please.

Comment: So, `cash-flow-plan.php` simply needs to check the application's authentication mechanism (session?  cookies?  etc.) for the unique identifier of the current logged-in user and make use of that identifier when querying the database.  Is there any reason why this wouldn't work in your application?

Comment: would i use something like this? 
`('".mysql_real_escape_string($this->session)."',
`

Comment: What is your current table structure? Right now it is hard to understand your problem.

Comment: i implemented this login script that someone made `http://blog.geotitles.com/2011/07/php-login-script/` to my website, where i have a form full numbers that a user has typed in and now been inerted into a table called cash_flow_plan, what im wanting is to take the active user with the current session and insert that form data i was previously talking about into a new row WITH the current users username as the primary key in the cash_flow_plan table. 

Hope that makes better sense.